# how to call formWindowClosing event in ButtonActionPerformEvent

Tags: java, swing

i have created ButtonActionPerformEvent call dispose Method.how dispose method call formwindowclosing event. for current class and open another class

```
private void Cmd01ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
            GVar=Txt01.getText();
            dispose(**formWindowClosing**(-)); // how i can pass form closing event here.
    }
```

one more **FormWindowClosing** Event i create antoher class object with setVisible True.

```
 private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
        new GlobalVariableClass2().setVisible(true);  //another class
}
```

kindly help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 3):

first of all this question isn't answerable

1) use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) rather that to call `create/close/dipose/setVisible` for [Top Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

2) don't create lots `Top Level Container`, reuse that for another usage, then you have to look for `setVisible` and in this case you have to set [setDefaultCloseOperation to HIDE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), notice for each `Top Level Container` is there implemented different methods for close operations

Comment: ok even i can setDefaultCloseOperation  is it possible one event call in another event                                         private void Cmd01ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
            GVar=Txt01.getText();
            //dispose(getWindows(formWindowClosing(new WindowEvent())));
            setDefaultCloseOperation();
            getWindows(formWindowClosing());
    } private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
            new GlobalVariableClass2().setVisible(true);

    }

Comment: no idea what did you tried, for real help sooner please edit your question with http://sscce.org/,